# Disable a RadioGroup when a progress bar is active: Android

Tags: android, radio-group

I have a RadioGroup containing two RadioButtons. 
I want to disable the RadioGroup view when the progress bar is active.
Any ideas?

Comment: view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); and view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); should do the trick. Some code might be helpful in any discussion ;O)

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please show us relevant code and where you are stuck

Answer (score 1):

Just set `setClickable(false)` for each radioButton.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if (progressBar.isShowing()){
for(int i = 0; i < rg1.getChildCount(); i++){
    ((RadioGroup)rg1.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(false);
}
}
```